# return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] return candidate

Tags: c

I'm learning C, but I find those vague compiler error messages increasingly frustrating. Here's my code:

```
char getkey (int minimo, int maximo, int alphalen, int index, char alpha[])  
{  
    int cociente, residuo, cont;
    int i = 0;
    char cand[maximo+1];
    char candidate[maximo+1];

    while (index != 0)
    {
        cociente = index / alphalen;
        residuo = index%alphalen;
        cand[i] = residuo;
        index = cociente;
        i+=1;
    }

    for (cont=i-1; cont>=0; cont--)  
    {   
        int pos = cand [cont];
        candidate[i] = alpha[pos];      
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

This generates one warning:

- return makes integer from pointer without a cast

  - return candidate;

Can someone explain these warning?

Comment: Your function expects to return char, but are you returning char?

Comment: candidate is not a char

Comment: Your function is declared as returning `char` but you are trying to return a `char *`.

Comment: candidate is a char array, not a char and your function is declared so that the return value is expected to be that of a char.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your local variable `candidate` is an array of char.  When you say

```
return candidate;
```

you return a pointer to char.  (This is due to the very close relationship between arrays and pointers in C, which you will have to learn about if you don't know yet.)  But you've stated that your function `getkey` returns a char, not a pointer-to-char.

You need to make the function's return value match its type.  You might want change the `return` statement so it returns a single char.  If you want to have the function return a whole string, you could change its declaration to `char *getkey()`, but in that case you'll also have to take care of the allocation of the `candidate` array.

Here's what the warning means.  You tried to return a pointer.  The function is supposed to return a character, which is represented as a small integer.  The compile is willing to try to convert the pointer to an integer, in case that's what you really want to do, but since that's not usually a good idea, it warns you.  Indeed, in this case the warning tells you that you probably made a mistake.

Comment: Is it really known as "equivalence of arrays and pointers in C"? Because that's not true. Arrays can decay into pointers under certain contexts (i.e. passing and returning) but they are not pointers.

Comment: @Kevin "Equivalence" is what we used to call it.  (Does nobody use that term any more?) "Equivalence" does not mean they're the same thing; just that they're closely -- even intimately -- related.  See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html .

Comment: No, arrays and pointers are not closely related. One is a memory address, the other is _n_ elements laid out contiguously in memory.

Comment: @tuple_cat "If arrays and pointers are not closely related", asks user5672720, "then when I tried to return an array from my function, why did it return a pointer instead?"

Comment: @Adam Thanks, didn't think about that in this case.  Edited some more.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Actually "we" never used the term "equivalent", because it is plain wrong: `sizeof(int [10])` and `sizeof(&(int[10]))`) are not equivalent. But your rephreased text is fine.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that looks much better.

Answer (score 2):

`getkey` has been declared to return a `char`, but you're trying to return `candidate` which is a `char` array.

You probably meant to return one of the elements in the array, i.e. something like `candidate[x]`.

The reason for the error message saying "pointer" instead of "array" is that the compiler is converting `candidate` to a pointer to the first element in the array, which happens implicitly in some contexts, for example when returning, since arrays can't be returned (or passed as parameters) by value in C (see [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/3425536)).